# Python: how to select n number of elements of each type from OrderedDict?

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a Django serializer returning an `OrderedDict` from the `serializer.data`. It can contain for example this type of data:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('type', 'A')]), OrderedDict([('id', '2'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('type', 'A')]), OrderedDict([('id', '3'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('type', 'B')]), OrderedDict([('id', '4'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('type', 'B')]),
OrderedDict([('id', '5'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('type', 'C')]), OrderedDict([('id', '6'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('type', 'C')])]
```

I'd like to take the first element of each `type` and make a json out of that data. I could use for -loops to iterate through the dict and make a new list containing one element of each type: A, B and C. I'd like to know if there's some cleaner and neater way to go through the dict and select n number from each `type`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `islice` with a generator against that list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
import itertools as it 

odl=[OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('type', 'A')]), OrderedDict([('id', '2'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('type', 'A')]), OrderedDict([('id', '3'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('type', 'B')]), OrderedDict([('id', '4'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('type', 'B')]),
OrderedDict([('id', '5'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('type', 'C')]), OrderedDict([('id', '6'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('type', 'C')])]

n=3

>>> list(it.islice((t for od in odl for t in od.items() if t[0]=='type'),0,n))
[('type', 'A'), ('type', 'A'), ('type', 'B')]
```

If you are looking to get `n` of each type, then use `groupby` with the same `islice`:

```
n=1
for k,v in it.groupby(sorted(odl, key=lambda od: od['type']), key=lambda od: od['type']):
    print(list(it.islice((t for od in v for t in od.items() if t[0]=='type'),0,n)))
```

Prints:

```
[('type', 'A')]
[('type', 'B')]
[('type', 'C')]
```